# Earthdata log in error for downloading MODIS data (R language)

Tags: gdal, r, remote-sensing, modis, modis-reprojection-tool

I feel like I have followed all the correct steps on what is listed online here is my code: (and of course I have my correct earthdata username and password listed).

```
setwd("~")
library(MODIS)
library(raster)

EarthdataLogin(usr = "", pwd = "", path = "~/.netrc")

getHdf("MOD13Q1", collection = "006", tileH = 17, tileV = 4, 
        begin = "2000.02.18", end= "2023.02.17")
    Error in .local(product, ...) : 
  Earthdata Login credentials could not be verified.
Please run `MODISoptions(check_earthdata_login = TRUE)` (default) and re-try.
```

Then I run what the error result is commenting on:

```
MODISoptions(check_earthdata_login = TRUE)

STORAGE:
_______________
localArcPath : C:/Users/Aaron Elphick/Documents/Ecology and Data Science/Dissertation/OutputDestinationFolder 
outDirPath   : C:/Users/Aaron Elphick/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpSyTmtH/MODIS_ARC/PROCESSED 


DOWNLOAD:
_______________
EarthdataLogin   : FALSE 
MODISserverOrder : LAADS, LPDAAC 
dlmethod         : auto 
stubbornness     : high 
wait             : 0.5 
quiet            : FALSE 


PROCESSING:
_______________
GDAL           : 3.5.2 
MRT            : Enabled 
pixelSize      : asIn 
outProj        : asIn 
resamplingType : NN 
dataFormat     : GTiff 
cellchunk      : 1
```

Now even though I have used the earthdatalogin() function it is still saying that I have not logged in for some reason? (I presume due to the result shown: EarthDataLogin: False)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
MODIS:::checkEarthdataLogin()
```

(yes, three `:::` in there) This is an internal `MODIS` function, but its the most direct test of login credentials I can find (there seems to be a bug with `MODISoptions`, I've reported it).

It should either say:

```
> MODIS:::checkEarthdataLogin()
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
Authentication failed with
> HTTP error 401.
Please check your Earthdata credentials in ~/.netrc or re-enter via `EarthdataLogin()`.
```

or

```
> MODIS:::checkEarthdataLogin()
[1] TRUE
```

If it fails, check your `~/.netrc` file for credentials for the `urs.earthdata.nasa.gov` machine entry. Its possible they've been overwritten.

The way the `MODIS` package works is that the `EarthdataLogin` function doesn't "log you in" to the system, it writes the username and password to the `~/.netrc` file. You only have to do this once ever on this computer (unless you change username, password, or otherwise lose your `~/.netrc` file). Then the other `MODIS` functions look into this file whenever they need a username and password for the server.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply in the end I tried some more options on stackoverflow and specifying the MODISserverOrder in the MODISoptions enabled me to enter my username and password which enabled access to the data, and changed the Earthdatalogin to 'True'. Really appreciate the feedback though!
'''MODISoptions(MODISserverOrder = "LPDAAC", quiet = FALSE)

Comment: Yeah I suspect you overwrote your .netrc file at some point.